# Cannot Connect to DocumentDB elastic cluster with Compass

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, mongodb-compass, aws-documentdb, aws-documentdb-mongoapi

I have created an DocumentDB *elastic* cluster and I'm able to connect to it successfully from my local machine using `mongosh` once I figured out I needed to disable `retryWrites`.

I'd love to be able to connect to it from Compass or a similar application, but when I try to connect in Compass, it looks like it initially connects, but it throws this error:

```
An error occurred while loading instance info: Unknown admin command connectionStatus
```

After doing some digging, it appears that the DocumentDB implementation of the Mongo API for the *elastic* cluster doesn't include the connectionStatus command:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/mongo-apis.html

Does anyone have a work around to connect to DocumentDB Elastic using Compass or know a similar GUI that works around this deficiency? I would hate to throw away the convenience and savings of an elastic db solution for the ability to use a GUI, but it can be a pretty important feature.

Comment: If you need just a GUI check Studio 3T, also there is official documentation for the same https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/studio3t.html

Comment: I tried Robo 3T and it was able to connect to this DocumentDB instance!  It does look like there's a few bugs for some functions when the Mongo API isn't all 'there', but it looks fairly functional.  I'll see if anyone has any other ideas for using Compass.  If not, I'll make this the answer for now.